# How to create dial chart using aChart Engine for android?

Tags: android, achartengine

Now i am doing chart application in android using aChart Engine. I can created bar chart, line chart, dual line chart,pie chart and combined chart too. Now i want to create dial chart for my application. I need to create dial chart. I searched a lot but i couldn't get proper solution. Can any body tell me how to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dial chart in AChartEngine.

Please take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/WeightDialChart.java) example for getting some ideas.

Comment: Yes , I tried with that . But i can't able to move that needle . My question is , is it possible to rotate that needle manually?

Comment: Just set a different value and call chartView.repaint().